# Label conflict attribute prioritization in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling

Is it possible to resolve label conflicts within a feature class using an attribute value?

I have two points whose labels would overlap. These points have different numeric attributes and I'd like to prioritize the point with the greater value. The points are added via a Query Layer from a SQL Server that frequently changes.